# I can't show the second image I load in jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, paint

I am trying to load a background image in a JPanel, and then over this JPanel I want to add other objects of the JLabel type. But it does not show me the objects that I am adding.
Is it possible to add JButton or JLable objects on a JPanel that has a paint method?
The problem is that when I add the background image it does not allow me to visualize the different objects.
Inglés

In the example I can load the background image with the name "/MAPA_NRO1.png" but I cannot see the JLabel image called "/floor.png"

````
public class Principal extends JFrame

{
    
    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{
        Image imagen;
        
        public ImagePanel(Image im)
        {
            imagen=im;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;
            g2d.drawImage(imagen, 0, 0, 450,600,null);
            
        }
    }

    
    InputStream imgStream;
    Image fondo;
    ImagePanel imgfondo;
    ImagePanel imgpiso;
    JLabel piso;
    
        public Principal()
        {
            setBounds(100,100,450,600);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setResizable(false);
            
            piso=new JLabel();
            piso.setBounds(-130,470,580,180);
            iniciarComponentes();
            imgfondo=new ImagePanel(fondo);
            imgfondo.setBounds(0, 0, 450, 600);
            imgfondo.add(piso);
            this.add(imgfondo);
            
            
            pack();
            
        }
        
        public void iniciarComponentes()
        {
            
            try
            {
                imgStream=Principal.class.getResourceAsStream("/MAP_NRO1.png");
                fondo=ImageIO.read(imgStream);
                
                piso.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/floor.png")));
                
                
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
}```
````

Comment: You didn't invoke super.paint() so you lose the default painting code which is responsible for painting the child components added to the panel. The solution is to: 1) do custom painting by overriding `paintComponent()`, not paint(). 2) Make sure you invoke `super.paintComponent(g)` as the first statement. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples. Keep a link to the tutorial handy for all Swing basics.

Comment: Also, `piso.setBounds(-130,470,580,180);` setBounds doesn't work when adding components that use most layout managers, here a JFrame's contentPane which uses a BorderLayout by default. One (bad) solution is to give the JFrame's contentPane a null layout. a much *better* solution is to not use `setBounds(...)` or `setSize(...)` and instead learn about and use the Swing layout managers to maximal benefit.

Comment: "Is it possible to add JButton or JLable objects on a JPanel that has a paint method?"  First, it's the paintComponent method.  Second, yes it's possible but not recommended.  Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should do something.  Once you paint with the paintComponent method, you should paint everything with the paintComponent method.  JButtons and JLabels belong in a separate but equal control JPanel.

Comment: To make your code more of an [mre] post it using web images. 
 See an example and more help [here](https://ideone.com/FNeUrz)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc *JButtons and JLabels belong in a separate but equal control JPanel.* - why? Doesn't make sense to me. The OP is trying to create a panel with a background image. I'm not aware of any reason to not set the layout manager of the panel and then add components directly to the panel. It sounds like you are suggesting to create a second panel with a layout manager and then make it non-opaque and add components to this panel and then add this panel to the background panel.